# How to organize floating box elements (with varying height) into rows (with JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, yui

I have a list of block elements. Every block element has some height (that varies). I'd like to organize block elements into rows.

First attempt was to iterate over all elements and set their height to the one of heighest element. However, this causes gaps between rows as there is always one element significantly heighter than others.

So, I'd like to do the same, but detect rows and set height accordingly. However, I have problem doing that as `element.getComputedStyle('left')` returns `undefined` on floating elements.

Other function I can use (using YUI, but that should not matter)? Or use another approach entirely?

Comment: Instead of creating rows of fixed-height elements in order to remove gaps... Can you consider using http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html ?

Comment: David Desandro made a framework agnostic version of masonry that doesn't require jQuery: https://github.com/desandro/vanilla-masonry. I'm (slowly) working on a port for YUI3. When I finish it I'll publish it in the YUI Gallery

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use this pure CSS solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
</div>    

<div class="row">
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
    <div>I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.I can't. As much as I care about you, my first duty is to the ship. The unexpected is our normal routine.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:25%;
}
```

Link to jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/innerurge1/Ys5Kw/